# Django crispy-forms add javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-crispy-forms

To build my forms in Django i use crispy-forms to generate the Template HTML. To enable real-time calculations i want to use JavaScript in these forms. As the HTML is generated i am unsure in how to add the on-change element to these forms when using the crispy-forms template:

```
self.template = 'bootstrap3/table_inline_formset.html'
```

When using a template i am not able to use the Layout/Field option to override the generated HTML. Where can i control the rendered HTML when using the self.template so i can add the the on-change element to the rendered HTML?

```
<select id="order" name='order' onchange="calculateTotal()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following code to the helper did the trick, even when using the template.

```
self.layout = Layout(
    Field('orderline_quantity', onkeyup="orderlineTotal()")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
order = document.getElementById('id_order');
order.addEventListener("change", calculateTotal);
```

When forms are generated from django the id normally is "id_fieldname"...shouldn't be hard to get the fields you need